# Incorrect display of bubble sort method with an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

i'm a newbie in Java so I have a problem with the "Bubble Sort Method".
First, here is my code so far:

```
    import javax.swing.*;

public class arreglo_unidimensional_con_menu
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int original[];
        int n = 0, r = 0, aux = 0, num = 0, help = 0, indice = 0, posicion = 0, orden = 0;
        String op;
        boolean flag = false, band = false;
        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduzca el tamaño del Arreglo", "Inicialización", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        original = new int[n];
        do
        {

            op = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Selecciona una opción: \n a) Insertar\n b) Mostrar\n c) Ordenar\n d) Buscar\n s) Salir", "Menú del Arreglo", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE).toUpperCase());
            switch(op)
            {
                case "A":
                    if(indice < n)
                    {
                        original[indice]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduzca un número: ", "Entrada de Datos", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                        indice++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Arreglo ya NO tiene Espacio Disponible");
                    }
                    break;
                case "B":
                    System.out.println("Arreglo: \n");
                    for(int ctrl = 0; ctrl < indice; ctrl++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(original[ctrl]+" ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    break;
                case "C":
                    while(flag == false)
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        if(indice < n)
                        {
                            for(int ctrl = 0; ctrl < indice-1 && ctrl < n-1; ctrl++)
                            {
                                if(original[ctrl] > original[ctrl+1])
                                {
                                    help = original[ctrl];
                                    original[ctrl] = original[ctrl+1];
                                    original[ctrl+1] = help;
                                    flag = false;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(indice == n)
                        {
                            for(int ctrl = 0; ctrl < n-1; ctrl++)
                            {
                                if(original[ctrl] > original[ctrl+1])
                                {
                                    /*help = original[ctrl+1];
                                    original[ctrl+1] = original[ctrl];
                                    original[ctrl] = help;*/

                                    help = original[ctrl];
                                    original[ctrl] = original[ctrl+1];
                                    original[ctrl+1] = help;
                                    flag = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                break;
                case "D":
                    num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el número a buscar: "));
                    while(band == false)
                    {
                        for(int ctrl = 0; ctrl < n; ctrl++)
                        {
                            if(original[ctrl] == num)
                            {
                                band = true;
                                posicion = ctrl;
                            }
                        }
                        if(band == true)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tú número "+num+" si está en el Arreglo y ocupa el índice: "+posicion);
                            band = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tú número "+num+" no está en el Arreglo");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "S":
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opción Incorrecta", "FATAL ERROR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }while(aux < n);
    }
}
```

The purpose of the program is create a Menu for an array for ordering, searching and display. 
But the important thing is that the "Bubble Sort Method" which is **THE OPTION C** is not working well for me, I need to add "N" int values but I don't have to fill the entire Array, for example:

Array [value] = 5
Then the user introduces one by one the elements for the array:

3 2 1 ...but the array can't be full.

So the "Bubble Sort" has to return me:

1 2 3 ...so when I introduce a new element (like the zero) it may put in order.

0 1 2 3

What I'm doing wrong?
Sorry for my english by the way I'm not from te US, but I really need your help.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Which line(s) of code are "not working", and what exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: Do you see the part that says case "C", well in that part the next 17 lines until the "break" are not displaying what I need. I need that the Bubble Sort order all the numbers in a single run.

Comment: Ok let me be more specific. Let's suppose that the user wants an array of 5 numbers, then he chooses option "A" and add the first number, then he chooses again option "A" and add the second number. Before he add the fifth number, he chooses option "C" for order the array. In this moment is where my problem is, the Bubble Sort method only order the first 2 numbers, and the other have to repeat the Option "C" to get their right place. Am I a little bit clear now?

Comment: This would be a lot easier to read if you refactored your code so that each of the cases, as well as the user input retrieval were individual functions.

Comment: Do you mean like in different classes or something like that? I was thinking about it but the truth is that I don't know how to create a class yet. I'm still in the very basics.

Comment: Oh my! I'm sorry guys, I can't even explain what I want, is just that I'm tired of searching the answer for this stupid thing, that I don't even know why I need to implement, honestly I hate my teacher :( Doesn't matter anyway, I believe the Bubble Sort must be incompatible for my purposes. Thanks anyway.